# Jetpack compose accessibility with switch role

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, talkback

I'm trying to get a voiceover similar to XML:

1. First the text is announced
2. Then the state of the switch

The expected result is "Sometext on switch" or "Sometext off switch".

In Jetpack Compose it reads "Off sometext off switch" if you double-click it(using talkback to change state) and click again or swipe(to next and back), it reads "On sometext off switch".

Moreover, there is no sounding after double-clicking and changing state to on/off(like XML).

```
var isChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

val toggleModifier =
    Modifier.toggleable(
        value = isChecked,
        onValueChange = { isChecked = it },
        role = Role.Switch
    )

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val rowModifier = toggleModifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .align(Alignment.Center)
    Row(modifier = rowModifier) {
        Text(text = "Sometext")
        Switch(checked = isChecked, onCheckedChange = null)
    }
}
```

The second idea was to combine the text and the switch with mergeDescendants, but they are selected separately:

```
var isChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

val toggleModifier =
    Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val rowModifier = toggleModifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .align(Alignment.Center)
    Row(modifier = rowModifier) {
        Text(text = "Sometext")
        Switch(checked = isChecked, onCheckedChange = { isChecked = !isChecked })
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue even in the latest compose version `1.1.1`. It has already been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193427848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Utkarsh Tiwari mentioned in comments, it's compose bug, not fixed yet. They advice to use `Role.Checkbox` instead temporarily, it works as expected. Or do not use role at all

btw it's better to use `Modifier.then(rowModifier)`, then just `modifier = rowModifier`. So in the end it should be something like

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}
.then(rowModifier)
```